# Modeling courses and pre-requisites in the database

Tags: sql, database-design, model

Basic scenario: I have students, courses, and course-requirements that need to be stored in the database.

Anyone has any insight into the best way to store these and traverse course prerequisites?

1) Simple example:

- C: Math 100, prereq: none
- C: Math 150, prereq: none
- C: Math 200, prereq: Math 101, Math 150

Student A completed Math 100. How does one determine if he is eligible to take CS200 via database querying?

2) More complicated example:

- C: Chem 100, prereq: none
- C: Chem 200, prereq: Chem 100
- C: Chem 201, prereq: Chem 200
- C: Chem 202, prereq: Chem 200
- C: Chem 300, prereq: any two of Chem 200, Chem 201, Chem 202

Student B completed Chem 100, Chem 200, Chem 203. How do you check that he is eligible to take Chem 300?

How to model the pre-requisites hierarchy in the database? Any advice, links, references would be most welcome.

Comment: Swartz.  You need to read your answers and respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are are few things you have not thought about, as in Entities that need to be defined, that are implicit in your question.  Permit me to include a few, but do not get distracted by them, I am focusing on your stated question.  You can safely ignore `Grade, Teacher`, etc for now and contemplate them for the future.

[**Typical Data Model for a College**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Swartz%20DM.pdf)

[**IDEF1X Notation,**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Notation.pdf) for those who need explanation of the symbols.

- There is no need to add Surrogate keys unless they are required, due the the natural key becoming too large to carry into the children; I have not blindly stamped them as PK on every table.  In any case, the consideration is at the physical, not logical level.
- I modelled a RDb for a local university once.  I think in addition to pre-requisites such as *"any two of ...",* you may need *"and at least one of ..."*, so I have provided for any combination of those.
- `Requisite` contains the full list of possible requisites

  - `IsMandatory` identifies that the Requisite is Madatory required to fulfil the *"at least one of ..."*; the remainder are not, and fall into the *"any two of ..."*
  - `Grade` allows a minimum Grade to be specified as requisite
    .
- `Course.NumRequisite` identifies the number, of the possible `Requisites`, that are required, as in *"any **two** of ..."*

If you need SQL code to navigate the structure, please ask.

Comment: Thanks for the information, posting the SQL code would help greatly, especially handling the cases of "at least one of" and "any two of".
More specifically, I have a question relating to this, I'd much appreciate it if you could give it a look (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519140/compound-course-prerequisites-one-or-more-of-a-b-c-and-either-x-or-y-as-well-as).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the following would do most of what you want:

```
Table COURSE
  ID_COURSE    NUMBER         PRIMARY KEY
  DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR2(200)

Table PREREQUISITE_COURSE
  ID_COURSE         NUMBER    REFERENCES COURSE.ID_COURSE
  ID_PREREQ_COURSE  NUMBER    REFERENCES COURSE.ID_COURSE
  PRIMARY KEY (ID_COURSE, ID_PREREQ_COURSE)

Table STUDENT
  ID_STUDENT        NUMBER    PRIMARY KEY

Table STUDENT_COURSE
  ID_STUDENT        NUMBER    REFERENCES STUDENT.ID_STUDENT
  ID_COURSE         NUMBER    REFERENCES COURSE.ID_COURSE
  COMPLETED         CHAR(1)   CHECK(IN('Y', 'N'))
  PASSED            CHAR(1)   CHECK(IS NULL OR IN ('Y', 'N'))
```

Given the above the query to check to see if a student has successfully completed all coursework to take a given class would actually be easier if the query was written to return the pre-requisite courses the student HAD NOT taken - something like

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM STUDENT s
INNER JOIN COURSE STUDENT_COURSE sc
  ON (sc.ID_STUDENT = s.ID_STUDENT)
LEFT OUTER JOIN PREREQUISITE_COURSE pc
  ON (pc.ID_PREREQ_COURSE = sc.ID_COURSE)
INNER JOIN COURSE c
  ON (c.ID_COURSE = pc.ID_COURSE)
WHERE s.ID_STUDENT = <id of student of interest> AND
      c.ID_COURSE = <id of course of interest> AND
      sc.COMPLETED = 'Y' AND
      sc.PASSED = 'Y' AND
      pc.ID_PREREQ_COURSE IS NULL
```

Note that this hasn't been tested in any way and may contain some hideous logic errors (I'm a little leery of the late join of the COURSE table, for instance) but it should be useful as something to get started with.  Or, to quote the philosopher Pratchett

**Not tested on animals - you'll be the first!**

Share and enjoy.